# Samsung J5 stuck on Downloading Mode

Tags: samsung

The big problem it's that the phone doesn't have the power button at all, so I can't use the usual combination (VOLUME DOWN + POWER).

Any idea what can i do?

Comment: how do you power it on if it doesn't have a power button?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and I tried the volume buttons option and I don't think there's any other way that's not exclusive to your phone. You might just have to take it the manufacturer